# Error adding data in mysql table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a simple CURD operation using PHP and MYSQL. However I'm not able to insert/add data in the created table.

I think it might be a syntax error itself, but I can't figure out which one. The rest of the code works fine.

operation.php:

```
require_once("../CRUD/php/db.php");

$conn = createDB();

if(isset($_POST['create']))
{
    createData();
}

function createData()
{
    $name = textboxValue("name_type");
    $age = textboxValue("age_type");
    $gender = textboxValue("gender_type");
    $email = textboxValue("email_type");
    $contact = textboxValue("contact_type");
    $dept = textboxValue("dept_type");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO details(name,age,gender,email,contact,department)
                VALUES('$name', '$age', '$gender', $email', '$contact', '$dept');";

    if(mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'],$sql))
    {
        echo "Data added";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error adding data";
    }
}

function textboxValue($value)
{
    $textbox = mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['conn'], trim($_POST[$value]));
    if(empty($textbox))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return $textbox;
    }
}
```

"Error adding data" gets echoed. I can share the html code as well if needed.

Comment: Change your error message to include `mysqli_error($GLOBALS['conn']);`

Comment: You forgot a quote before `$email`. You should learn to use prepared statements instead of substituting variables, then you won't have problems like this.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks a lot man! It worked! The missing quote was the issue, and I'll make sure to learn to use prepared statements. xD

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: This `textboxValue` function is extremely dangerous and should not be used. Manual escaping is hugely problematic, as you've demonstrated in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO details(name,age,gender,email,contact,department)
                VALUES(\"$name\", \"$age\", \"$gender\", \"$email\", \"$contact\", \"$dept\");";
```

and so? By the way one quote you forgot near $email

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes.

Comment: Why use escaped double quotes instead of single quotes? It's less standard, and it's harder to read.

Comment: The only problem was the missing quote, there's no need to change all the other quotes just to fix that. This question should just be closed as a typo.

Comment: the person uses $GLOBALS, and you talk about the correct code? :)

Comment: I don't expect the people who post questions to know any better. I have higher expectations of answers.